# How to get Custom Assembly Attribute with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, assemblies

In the AssemblyInfo files of a .net project one can specify a custom assembly attribute via

[assembly: AssemblyMetadata("key1", "value1")]

My question is how does one retrieve this value from a compiled .net assembly via powershell?  I'm able to read all the standard attributes like fileversion, companyname, etc. but I'm having a heck of a time getting the value of this custom attribute (key1)

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
32# (get-date).GetType().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes([Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute], $false)

Copyright                                                   TypeId
---------                                                   ------
© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.              System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute
```

Instead of `get-date` use an instance from the assembly you're interested in.  Also substitute the Assembly*Attribute that you are interested in retrieving.

In the specific case of AssemblyMetadataAttribute, it is new to .NET 4.5.  PowerShell is still on .NET 4.0.  So you have to use the reflection only context to get this attribute:

```
$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("$pwd\ClassLibrary1.dll")
[reflection.customattributedata]::GetCustomAttributes($assembly)
```

Spits out:

```
AttributeType                 Constructor                   ConstructorArguments
-------------                 -----------                   --------------------
System.Runtime.Versioning.... Void .ctor(System.String)     {".NETFramework,Version=v4...
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"ClassLibrary1"}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {""}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {""}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"CDL/TSO"}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"ClassLibrary1"}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"Copyright © CDL/TSO 2013"}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {""}
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String, ... {"key1", "value1"}
System.Runtime.InteropServ... Void .ctor(Boolean)           {(Boolean)False}
System.Runtime.InteropServ... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"945f04e1-dae3-4de6-adf6-...
System.Reflection.Assembly... Void .ctor(System.String)     {"1.0.0.0"}
System.Diagnostics.Debugga... Void .ctor(DebuggingModes)    {(System.Diagnostics.Debug...
System.Runtime.CompilerSer... Void .ctor(Int32)             {(Int32)8}
System.Runtime.CompilerSer... Void .ctor()                  {}
```

Note the `key1` ane `value1` in the output.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried a lot of something's already brotha.  How about a snippet that will work?

Comment: `Exception calling "GetCustomAttributes" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'WebActivatorEx,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b26dc2a43f6a0d4' because it has not been preloaded. When using the
ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event."`

Looks like this method does not allow assemblies that have dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Building off @Keith Hill -

```
$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("$pwd\ClassLibrary1.dll")
$metadata = @{}
[reflection.customattributedata]::GetCustomAttributes($assembly) | Where-Object {$_.AttributeType -like "System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadataAttribute"} | ForEach-Object { $metadata.Add($_.ConstructorArguments[0].Value, $_.ConstructorArguments[1].Value) }
```

Gets you the AssemblyMetadata converted into a dictionary object.  You can get just the value using:

```
$metadata["key1"]
```

Resulting in:

```
value1
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Fails for me. `Exception calling "GetCustomAttributes" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'WebActivatorEx,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b26dc2a43f6a0d4' because it has not been preloaded. When using the
ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event."`

Looks like this method does not allow assemblies that have dependencies.