# How to Get Types F# Assembly with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, f#, .net-assembly

Is is possible to get the GetTypes() of an assembly from powershell?

this answer at [How to get Custom Assembly Attribute with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168320/how-to-get-custom-assembly-attribute-with-powershell)

works well for C# assembly but not for F# assembly

EDIT

I have this script that works well for C# assembly.

```
Param([String]$path)
$asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($path)
$asm.GetTypes() | select Name, BaseType | Where {$_.BaseType -Match  "System.Object"}
```

But when I pass the path of  F# assembly.

`Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\POC\PowerShell\MySample.Fs.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."`

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not work well"?

Comment: hope now I am more clear

Comment: ideally it should work ?

Comment: Is the file *actually* a .NET assembly? Can you open it with `ildasm`, Reflector, or some other assembly decompiler?

Comment: let me try .. thanks

Comment: I realized that its possible to Get types from C# project but PowerShell script cant do it.

Comment: interesting reading: http://tahirhassan.blogspot.it/2014/06/embedding-f-in-powershell.html

Comment: What's the bitness of that assembly?

Comment: I  realised that PowerShell is not able to resolve the Dependency but Visual Studio can. That's why is such behaviour.